# Proof verification :"For some" or "for all"

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> **Theorem**:
>
> Let $A$ be a set. For a cover $C$ of $A$, let
>
> $$D=\{I_n + x: I_n \in C, x\in\Bbb R\}$$
>
> Prove that $D$ covers $A+x$.
>
> **Proof**:
>
> Given:
>
> 1. Two sets $A$ and $A+x$.
> 2. $C$ is a cover for $A$. That is 
>      $C=\{I_n|A\subseteq UI_n\}$
> 3. $D=\{I_n+x|I_n\in C\}$
>
> To prove:$D$ covers $A+x$.
>
> That is, to prove $A+x \subseteq \cup(I_n+x)$.
>
> For that let $a_1+x\in A+x$ for some $a_1\in A$
>
> $a_1\in A\;\implies a_1 \in \cup I_n\implies (a_1+x)\in \cup I_n+x$.
>
> That is $A+x \subseteq \cup(I_n+x)$.
>
> Hence $D$ covers $A+x$.

I am trying to learn proof writing.

This is one of my proofs, but my friends suggested that instead of using "for some " in the line "For that let $a_1+x\in A+x$ for some $a_1 \in A$" we should use "for all".I googled about quantifiers, read through the Wikipedia articles, but still, I am confused that why should I change that wording.

Comment: What does $U$ denote, the _universal set_ or should there be $\bigcup\;$? I think there should be either $\forall a\in $ or for some $a_{\color{red}{1}}\in A$ if you put an index. Also, use `$D=\{...\}$`

Answer (score 1):

If $p \in A+x$, then this means that $p = a + x$ for *some* $a\in A$. Your proof looks fine to me.